# How to use ESP8266-12E with PCF8574 as an I/O extender

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I am using [ESP8266-12E](https://www.axman.com/content/esp8266-12e-wifi-module) with a [PCF8574](https://www.axman.com/content/esp8266-12e-wifi-module) as an I/O Pins Extender.
There are videos on youtube to use the [PCF8574](https://www.axman.com/content/esp8266-12e-wifi-module) with an ESP8266-01, but my problem is that I'm unable to analyze the pin connections with an [ESP8266-12E](https://www.axman.com/content/esp8266-12e-wifi-module). 
In the youtube tutorial it is said that the *GPIO0* AND *GPIO2* will go to the *SDA* and *SLC* pins of the [PCF8574](https://www.axman.com/content/esp8266-12e-wifi-module), but then, in the case of ESP8266-12E, the pins will go to the PCF8547.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the link to Arduino UNO as you tagged your question?

Comment: sorry , i thought people who knows arduino things might also know this.

Comment: The '8C-ESP8266 Interface I2C' document may help, if you have access to it.  It's available on Scribd, which is non-free.  One can see the  [first page of '8C-ESP8266 Interface I2C'](https://www.scribd.com/document/305609130/8C-ESP8266-Interface-I2C-en-v1-0) without a Scribd subscription

Comment: @jwpat7 : thanks . only first page , unfortunately cover page is visible in free.

Comment: i guess very less people plays with such things o wat!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer .
The data sheet of ESP8266-12E explains everything. 
The pin diagram has the given tags which shows which pins we can use.

Comment: Would you mind detailing the answer so that your question can bring benefits to other people having the same question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20374)

Comment: @jfpoilpret, he IS the author...

Comment: i have added details to the answer.

Comment: @DatHa this comment was automatically generated from my delete vote; please don't think I can be so stupid, thanks.

Comment: @all : is my way wrong to provide and declare answer. if yes plz guide.

Comment: @karmaCoding, it could have a little more detail. You could add a wiring diagram and/or code you used to get it working. In that way, others can easily verify and/or use it.